Change and adjust car GPS device settings through WEB APP
I have a Teltonika FMB641 device and I want to communicate with it without using SMS and only through WEB Application. There was nothing written about this on the device site. And what I took from the device's documents was that the device only sends information to the web application, but only receives settings and information via SMS. Is there a way I can communicate with the device only through the web app? Do you know any source or have experience in this work, please help me
I read the device's document on the Teltonika company website and googled on the Internet, but I did not find anything about this.

How do you connect to the web app? There are two problems: exchanging data, and interface. First you should know all the way you can transmit data to the device. And do you really want that a device on your car is open to the entire internet? Note: it may be much cheaper to install a new GPS device compared to hack one. PS: probably there is a serial interface hidden somewhere
